# Slicing a string from end to begining

Tags: python, slice

I am trying to perform palindromic slicing on a string and comparing the forward version of a string vs to the backward version of the string

```
string = "nitin"
i = 0
j = len(string)

while i<j:
    if string[i:j] == string[j-1:i-1:-1]:
        print("".join(string[i:j]))
    i +=1 
    j-=1
```

but I found the string[end:start-1:-1] method doesn't accept a parameter such as string[4:-1:-1]. I understand why (because index -1 is the same as the start of the string) but I don't know how to overcome this problem using list slicing in combination with my method.

(I mean I could shorten the string each time but I'd rather be able to solve my problem using list slicing if possible) as below:

```
string = "nitin"
i = 0
j = len(string)

while i+1<j:
    string=string[i:j]
    if string == string[::-1]:
        print(string)
    i +=1 
    j-=1
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

**EDIT**
I want every possible sub-palindromic sequence
(e.g: nitin would give nitin, iti)

Comment: What's the expected output in your case?

Comment: If you want to check if a string is palindromic, just `string[::-1] == string`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check is a string palindromic, you can simply use [reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=reversed#reversed) function:

`''.join(reversed(string)) == string`

You can also use `reversed` in your loops because it returns an iterator:

> Return a reverse iterator. seq must be an object which has a **reversed**() method or supports the sequence protocol (the **len**() method and the **getitem**() method with integer arguments starting at 0).

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion to get all sub palindromic. The result is a `set` in order to remove all duplicate sub palindromic.

```
def sub_palindromic(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return set()
    elif len(s) == 2:
        if s[::-1] == s:
            return set([s])
        else:
            return set()
    else:
        if s[::-1] == s:
            return set([s]) | sub_palindromic(s[1:]) | sub_palindromic(s[:-1])
        else:
            return sub_palindromic(s[1:]) | sub_palindromic(s[:-1]) | sub_palindromic(s[:2]) | sub_palindromic(s[-2:])

sub_palindromic('nitin') # {'nitin', 'iti'}
sub_palindromic('abca') # set()
sub_palindromic('abab') # {'bab', 'aba'}
sub_palindromic('abba') # {'abba', 'bb'}
sub_palindromic("aaaaa") # {'aa', 'aaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaaa'}
sub_palindromic('abcbacab') # {'abcba', 'aca', 'bacab', 'bcb'}
sub_palindromic("1122bb2211") # {'11', '1122bb2211', '122bb221', '22', '22bb22', '2bb2', 'bb'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just combine `[::-1]` and regular array slicing?

```
In [2]: a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
In [4]: a[::-1]
Out[4]: [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
In [13]: a[::-1][:5]
Out[13]: [6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

So I guess if you apply that to a variable length string it would be

```
In [14]: f = 'pallapi'

In [15]: f[::-1][1:]
Out[15]: 'pallap'

In [16]: f[::-1][1:] == f[:-1]
Out[16]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
>>> foo = 'abcde'
>>> foo[::-1]
 'edcba'
>>> bar = 'nidin'
>>> bar == bar[::-1]
True
>>> foo == foo[::-1]
False
>>>
```